# How to Filter Search a Data with Leading Zero Specifically in c# MySql

Tags: c#, mysql

Hey Guys I have a Problem regarding 'Data Searching in MYSQL database'

the Problem is I want to Search a Specific Data

example:

**00136**

**000136**

So if i search **00136**

search result should be: **00136** only.

but the result is :

**00136**

**000136**

how do i make it Show  **00136** only? and not both.

Also this data formats are in VARCHAR

my code.

```
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("select id, code, color, type, price from singlecustomer_items where code like concat ('%',@search,'%') or type like concat ('%',@search,'%') or color like concat ('%',@search,'%') or price like concat ('%',@search,'%')", con);
                string search = "%" + SearchBox.Replace("%", @"\%") + "%";
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@search", search));

                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
                adapter.Fill(ResultDt);
                finditems.dataGrid.DataSource = ResultDt;
```

in this Context

I am only Searching for the Data **'code'** Column.

I've been searching problem with LEADING ZEROS
but all of them is about keeping the leading ZEROS
and not with a filtering search.

Comment: Just remove the '%'. Like '%00136%' make it fetch all results containing '00136' while like '00136' would fetch all results which are exactly '00136'.

Comment: it didn't work. when I remove % it doesn't show data anymore,  I am still new at Filtering using sql parameter queries preventing sql injection. But I will figure it out, Thank you.

Comment: You re-add '%' a second time with the line "string search = "%" + SearchBox. ...+ "%"; you have  to remove it here as well.

Comment: Thank you very much Ostas I finally figured it out Earlier. I remove % and Remove Sanitation only for code. Now it works so good.

Comment: I'm glad that helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove % operator

it search like your input value, this is like operator

Comment: `where code like concat ('%',@search,'%')`

in this part 

I Should right it Like this

`where code like concat ('',@search,'')`

but still fetches

both **00136** and **000136**